# Why duplicates when adding dictionary to array

Tags: ios, swift, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I'm new to Swift and experimenting.  Trying to create a simple array of dictionary values.  This is crude, but I simply replicated a short piece of code four times for the dictionary objects, changed values in each section and then added each of the four to the array.

When I print the array, I am finding it contain four versions of the last dictionary object.  How can that be?  I would have expected the array for have four dictionary objects i.e one of each of the objects added.

```
func countDown()  {
    let dict: NSMutableDictionary = [:]
    let enduroArrayFile = NSMutableArray()

    dict.setObject(1, forKey: "SectionDistance")
    dict.setObject("S", forKey: "Direction")
    dict.setObject(0, forKey: "ArrivalTime")
    dict.setObject(0, forKey: "AverageSpeed")
    //saving dictionary to array
    enduroArrayFile.addObject(dict)

    dict.setObject(1.2, forKey: "SectionDistance")
    dict.setObject("S", forKey: "Direction")
    dict.setObject(0, forKey: "ArrivalTime")
    dict.setObject(0, forKey: "AverageSpeed")
    //saving dictionary to array
    enduroArrayFile.addObject(dict)

    dict.setObject(2, forKey: "SectionDistance")
    dict.setObject("R", forKey: "Direction")
    dict.setObject(0, forKey: "ArrivalTime")
    dict.setObject(0, forKey: "AverageSpeed")
    //saving dictionary to array
    enduroArrayFile.addObject(dict)

    dict.setObject(2.1, forKey: "SectionDistance")
    dict.setObject("S", forKey: "Direction")
    dict.setObject(0, forKey: "ArrivalTime")
    dict.setObject(0, forKey: "AverageSpeed")
    //saving dictionary to array
    enduroArrayFile.addObject(dict)

    print (enduroArrayFile)
}
```

The output is

```
(
    {
    ArrivalTime = 0;
    AverageSpeed = 0;
    Direction = S;
    SectionDistance = "2.1";
},
    {
    ArrivalTime = 0;
    AverageSpeed = 0;
    Direction = S;
    SectionDistance = "2.1";
},
    {
    ArrivalTime = 0;
    AverageSpeed = 0;
    Direction = S;
    SectionDistance = "2.1";
},
    {
    ArrivalTime = 0;
    AverageSpeed = 0;
    Direction = S;
    SectionDistance = "2.1";
    }
)
```

Comment: Because NSDictionary is a *reference type*. You create an array with 4 reference to the same one-and-only dictionary.

Comment: Consider to use Swift value types instead: Dictionary, Array, ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mistakenly reusing `dict` over and over. You need to create a new instance each time.

```
func countDown()  {
    let enduroArrayFile = NSMutableArray()

    var dict: NSMutableDictionary = [:]
    dict.setObject(1, forKey: "SectionDistance")
    dict.setObject("S", forKey: "Direction")
    dict.setObject(0, forKey: "ArrivalTime")
    dict.setObject(0, forKey: "AverageSpeed")
    //saving dictionary to array
    enduroArrayFile.addObject(dict)

    dict = [:]
    dict.setObject(1.2, forKey: "SectionDistance")
    dict.setObject("S", forKey: "Direction")
    dict.setObject(0, forKey: "ArrivalTime")
    dict.setObject(0, forKey: "AverageSpeed")
    //saving dictionary to array
    enduroArrayFile.addObject(dict)

    dict = [:]
    dict.setObject(2, forKey: "SectionDistance")
    dict.setObject("R", forKey: "Direction")
    dict.setObject(0, forKey: "ArrivalTime")
    dict.setObject(0, forKey: "AverageSpeed")
    //saving dictionary to array
    enduroArrayFile.addObject(dict)

    dict = [:]
    dict.setObject(2.1, forKey: "SectionDistance")
    dict.setObject("S", forKey: "Direction")
    dict.setObject(0, forKey: "ArrivalTime")
    dict.setObject(0, forKey: "AverageSpeed")
    //saving dictionary to array
    enduroArrayFile.addObject(dict)

    print (enduroArrayFile)
}
```

I don't know Swift well so I may have gotten the syntax wrong.

Comment: Thanks.  You nailed it.  I was thinking along similar lines but I would have expected to see the *first* dictionary values repeated four times, not the last set of values.  Seeing the last set four times has me totally confused.  Any idea why?

Comment: Sure. The dictionary's values are being replaced over and over. The last one wins.